# wkhtmltopdf - Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError

Tags: python, django, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to build a PDF file out of the HTML file. When I run the command to convert the HTML file the response was

```
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done                                                                      
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError
```

Answer (score 7):

****SOLUTION:****
This is for those with the error:

> Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError

If you get an error when uploading an image/media, you have to upload that image to your own http server or hosting, for example in XAMPP. Put the complete link of the image in the html, example:

```html
<img src='https://127.0.0.1/web/chart.jpg'>
```

In this way the images will be loaded well at the time of passing them to pdf. When creating the pdf, you can already delete the image from the hosting or remove the server.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use relative URLs and specify the enable-local-file-access option.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening when the renderer could not load a/some javascript/image/font file. After resolving missing resource, the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar experience and had encountered with the same error (Also I have put complete code in  [My GitHub](https://github.com/ieeexplorer/HTML-and-LINK-to-PDF-CONVERT-Convert-to-PDF-)). But my code was like this :

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url("https://www.google.com", "google.pdf" , configuration = config)
```

I changed **HTTPS** to **HTTP** and it fixed the error. like this :

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url("http://www.google.com", "google.pdf" , configuration = config)
```

Comment: Great catch, I spent a lot of time trying various things until I saw this!